# Display an image from within an RSS Feed Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, image, rss, feed

I'm trying to display an image from an RSS Feed. At the moment I am displaying the Title, Date, and Description by using the code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2><%# XPath("title") %></h2><br />
    <h3><%# XPath("pubDate") %></h3><br />
    <h3><%# XPath("description") %></h3><br />
    <a class ="btn btn-primary btn-lg" Target="_blank" href="<%# XPath("link") %>">Read More On This Story</a>
        </div>
    <hr />
</ItemTemplate>
```

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server"
DataFile="http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/education/rss.xml"
XPath="rss/channel/item">
```

After I add this image, I am looking to display each story within the page itself. To at the moment, it is opening up a new tab. I am looking to use possibly an iframe or a modal. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see that you have used link within a tag. There is nothing related to displaying image. As per your post, you are looking to display image from rss, correct? Can you please try to use img element and try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution to showing images from your rss feed:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2><%# XPath("title") %></h2>
    <br />
    <h3><%# XPath("pubDate") %></h3>
    <br />
    <h3><%# XPath("description") %></h3>
    <br />
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="_subitemsRepeater"
      EnableViewState="false"
      DataSource='<%# XPathSelect("media:thumbnail", XmlNamespaceManager) %>'>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <img src="<%# ((System.Xml.XmlNode)Container.DataItem).Attributes["url"].Value %>" />
        <br />
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
      <br />
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" target="_blank" href="<%# XPath("link") %>">Read More On This Story</a>
      </div>
      <hr />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server"
  DataFile="http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/education/rss.xml"
  XPath="rss/channel/item" />
```

In code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
  protected XmlNamespaceManager XmlNamespaceManager { get; set; }

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     XmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(XmlDataSource1.GetXmlDocument().NameTable);
     XmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("media", "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
  }

}
```

If your feed don't have multiple images you can replace repeater with a single image tag like this:

```
<img src="<%# XPath("media:thumbnail/@url", XmlNamespaceManager) %>" />
```